# Why doesn't my Edit function work with my mock server? Fetch happens before my Edit

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this small code that basically edits an entry on my mock server (the data is just in an array right now, not using a database). First, I was only doing the edit, then I realized in order to actually see the entry changed after an edit, I would have to reload the page and I don't want that, because it's bad from the clients point. Then I added a getClients method, that just fetched all the entries after an edit, but now the problem is, that the fetch for some reason, happens before the update, even though I specified it has to happen after the edit. Also, after a while, it just stops working, and I have no idea why. Can someone help? This is my code

```
const getClients = async () => {
const clientsFromServer = await fetchClients();
setClients(clientsFromServer);
```

};

```
    const onEdit = async (id, client) => {
    const modifiedClient = { ...client };
    try {
      await modifyClients(id, modifiedClient)
        .then(console.log("ready to fetch now"))
        .then(getClients());

      
    } catch {
      console.log("failed edit");
      console.error();
    }
  };
```

I am also calling this function in here in another component:

```
    const onModify = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    onEdit(clientData.id, { client, address, city, zip, country });
  };
```

And this onModify is basically called when a button is clicked

Comment: can you share where you're calling this function?

Comment: @boxdox hey, I added a edit with the code where I am calling it!

Comment: `.then(getClients());` try changing this line into `.then(() => getClients());`

Comment: @boxdox thank you, but it didn't work! Now it doesn't even do the fetch.

Comment: I have added my getClients() method as well, maybe that is a problem!

Comment: can you please set this up into a codesandbox like environment?

Comment: @boxdox hey, I figured it out. I had to put a small timeout, and now it works.
basically now I have
.then(await timeout(2000)).then(getClients()); and now it works perfectly